# Save temporary ansible shell scripts instead of deleting

Tags: ansible

I noticed Ansible removes the temporary script using a semi-colon to separate the bash commands.

Here is an example command:

```
EXEC ssh -C -tt -v -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 
ControlPath="/Users/devuser/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o
KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o
PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
-o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 build /bin/sh -c
'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python
/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1430847489.81-75617096172775/docker;
rm -rf
/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1430847489.81-75617096172775/
>/dev/null 2>&1'
```

Is there a way to tell ansible to replace the semi-colon with a double ampersand or to tell it to save the script or output the contents when running ansible-playbook?

I'm trying to debug an error in this script and right now the only thing that appears is this:

```
failed: [build] => {"changed": false, "failed": true}
msg: ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory')),)
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I found the environment variable -

```
export ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1
```

Set this, then re-run ansible-playbook, and then ssh and cd over to ~/.ansible/tmp/ to find the files.

Comment: This works for me. Are you checking the remote machine? That's where the python files are executed.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in to say that if your playbook targets `localhost`, Ansible *does* copy files to `~/.ansible/tmp` on the machine you used to run `ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1 ansible-playbook ...`. This makes it a bit easier to use [pdb-clone](https://bitbucket.org/xdegaye/pdb-clone/wiki/Home) for debugging. Just add (temporarily) `from pdb_clone import pdb; pdb.set_trace_remote()` directly in the Ansible sources near where you suspect the problem to lie, and then run `pdb-attach` in another terminal when it hits the breakpoint. (You can also debug remotely, but it's a bit more involved.)

Comment: where the files get stored in windows?