# Ansible Logging Extreme Detail How-To?

Tags: logging, ansible

I am finding a lack of detail using ansible-playbook with both the ansible.cfg log_path methodology plus with the -vvvvvvv.....

What am I missing? It's for all the tmp files which ansible creates in its excursions when
running on the remote host.

I want to know what's in those and have those detailed in the local instance from which I
am running ansible-playbook, preferably.

Anyway to get at that stuff locally (or remotely for that matter)?

Comment: That's answered here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060164/save-temporary-ansible-shell-scripts-instead-of-deleting

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"All the tmp files which ansible creates in its excursions ... have those detailed in the local instance"*

A: Use [ansible-runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The details are, you're looking for, will be stored in [Runner Artifacts Directory Hierarchy](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#runner-artifacts-directory-hierarchy). See examples of [Runner Artifact Job Events (Host and Playbook Events)](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#runner-artifact-job-events-host-and-playbook-events).

For example, running the simple play below

```
$ cat private1/project/test.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="Test!"

$ ansible-runner -p test.yml run private1

ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Test!"
}
```

will create artifacts

```
$ tree private1/artifacts/ebf1308b-2463-429b-88c9-db483955b07f/
private1/artifacts/ebf1308b-2463-429b-88c9-db483955b07f/
├── command
├── fact_cache
│   └── localhost
├── job_events
│   ├── 1-2ab0297b-7aba-4a36-902f-0c178084591d.json
│   ├── 2-803f5d14-b1d3-8779-c323-000000000006.json
│   ├── 3-803f5d14-b1d3-8779-c323-00000000000c.json
│   ├── 4-ba49573d-be94-486b-83f0-3708f7e95bb6.json
│   ├── 5-4767b624-4d02-41f0-99a4-7391cd43488f.json
│   ├── 6-803f5d14-b1d3-8779-c323-000000000008.json
│   ├── 7-768b19c7-1f49-4f3d-9f57-29d2944570f1.json
│   ├── 8-210d85b3-0a0c-4bfe-a919-57f3493aa232.json
│   └── 9-abf16371-08ab-4d6a-993c-c4a97f5124eb.json
├── rc
├── status
└── stdout
```

To see more details increase verbosity

```
$ ansible-runner -vvv -p test.yml run private1
```

And [Profiling](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#runner-profiling-data-directory) is available too.